# python reading string and converting to float

Tags: python

I am reading from a text file  and parsing through the line with the following line of code,

```
with open(srcfile) as src:
  for i, line in enumerate(src):
    word = line.split('\t')
```

And then i am trying to chance `word[0]` to float which `word[0]` appears in text file as 1345.  but i am getting can't convert string to float error message.  when i print `word[0]`, it's printing as ' 1 3 4 5 '.  anyone knows why it's doing this? and how to fix it so i can change it to float?  i have tried the following and it didn't work:

```
x=word[0].strip(' \t\n\r')
x=word[0].replace(' ','')
```

the text file is formated as

```
1345 O::2.16.840.1.111234.3.13.30.1.1.11,VENDOR::Stbks,TYPE::YYY    1   2204    1
```

Comment: You would need to show the text file you are using as well.

Comment: try `x=word[0].replace(' ','').replace('\t', '')`

Comment: Hard to tell for sure from the above, but perhaps the file is encoded in UCS-2 and you're reading it as UTF-8.

Comment: thanks for such a quick respond.
@Anand, the text file is formated as 
1345 O::2.16.840.1.111234.3.13.30.1.1.11,VENDOR::Stbks,TYPE::YYY 1 2204 1 
torek, I am suspecting the same thing... but how can i check the txt file what format it is in and how can i change the format i am reading?

Comment: Please update that in the question.

Comment: So I opened the file with Notepad++ and it does say the file type is UCS-2 LE BOM.  so @torek,  the issue might very well be what you have suggested.  now the question is how do i fix it.  
thanx again!

Comment: Not sure what the best way to fix it is.  You can deal with encoding issues in Python, or you can force your editor(s) to write the file in a sensible encoding like UTF-8 in the first place.  In general I'd prefer the latter but that's because I avoid Windows :-)  To open with codecs, see http://stackoverflow.com/a/5241941/1256452

Comment: @torek That question is out of date. You can just use the `encoding` argument of `open` now. eg. `open(srcfile, encoding="utf16")`

Comment: @Dunes: `encoding=` in `open` appears to be specific to Python 3.  I can't tell which Python is being used here based on the question.  (My own Python code is all Python2 for various reasons, many not so great any more :-) )

Comment: @torek the python 3 style open can be found at `io.open` in python 2. The builtin open wasn't replaced for backwards compatibility reasons.

Comment: @Dunes: aha, thanks.  I see that the bytes read via `io.open` when opening in text mode are returned as Unicode data (which overall is generally superior but requires additional adaptation).

Comment: it's confirmed that the issue is that the fact that the input file is ucs2 type.  and none of the in python suggestions worked for me.  i used powershell to convert to utf8 file and my python script is reading it fine... now as dirty as it sounds i am thinking to execute the powershell command-let within the python to change the file first then run the python script on the UTF8 file.